# VirtualBox Ubuntu boots in tiled mode on first start only

Tags: boot, virtualbox, display-resolution, reboot

I've come across a strange issue booting Ubuntu with bspwm in VirtualBox.

When I boot the VM for the first time, it will start in a small (non-fullscreen) resolution in tiled mode. This can be resolved by rebooting, without shutting off the VM instance. If I restart the VM entirely through VirtualBox the problem resets.

A very strange interaction imo. I can only guess it has to do with reading the VM resolution while booting initially?

Restarting bspwm with `bspc wm -r` has no effect. The only solution I've found is to reboot completely. After that it works fine until the next shutdown.

[Immediately after first boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ArM.png)

[After first boot with terminal, to show usable space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLrD1.png)

[After reboot, notice how polybar has showed up now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YUD.jpg)

[After reboot with terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIjYu.png)

Comment: Is _VirtualBox Guest Additions_ installed on the guest OS?

Comment: @FedKad Yes it is :)